# Saving an image with its thumb and showing on imageView android

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I am trying to save an image taken from camera and then storing it on sdCard along with its Thumb also showing this thumb on an imageView.
 However it gives error at Null pointer

```
 imageBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(imageBitmap, 40, 40, false);
```

What is wrong?

```
    {
            Intent intent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            try 
            {
              if (title.getText().toString().equals(""))
              {
                displayAlert("Please Input Title First","Error!");
              }
              else
              {

                Integer val = myMisc.miscId ;
                String fileName = "image" + "_" + title.getText().toString()+"_" + val.toString();
                photo = this.createFile(fileName, ".jpg");
                myMisc.filename = photo.getAbsolutePath();
                intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(photo));
                startActivityForResult(intent, RESULT_CAMERA_SELECT);
              }
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                Log.v("Error", "Can't create file to take picture!");
                displayAlert("Can't create file to take picture!","SDCard Error!");
            }
        }




public synchronized void onActivityResult(final int requestCode, int resultCode, final Intent data) 
    {
       if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) 
       {
           if (requestCode == RESULT_CAMERA_SELECT)
           {
               try 
               {
                   saveImage();
               }
               catch (IOException e) 
               {
                   e.printStackTrace();
               }
           }



public static int calculateInSampleSize(
            BitmapFactory.Options options, int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {
    // Raw height and width of image
    final int height = options.outHeight;
    final int width = options.outWidth;
    int inSampleSize = 1;

    if (height > reqHeight || width > reqWidth) {
        if (width > height) {
            inSampleSize = Math.round((float)height / (float)reqHeight);
        } else {
            inSampleSize = Math.round((float)width / (float)reqWidth);
        }
    }
    return inSampleSize;
}

    public void saveImage() throws IOException
    {
      try 
        {       
           FileInputStream is2 = new FileInputStream(photo);
           final BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
           options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
           Bitmap imageBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is2, null, options);
           options.inSampleSize = calculateInSampleSize(options, 40, 40);
           options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
           imageBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is2 ,null, options);
           imageBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(imageBitmap, 40, 40, false);
           Integer val = myMisc.miscId;
           String fileName = ".thumbImage" + "_" + title.getText().toString()+ "_" + val.toString();  
           photo = this.createFile(fileName, ".jpg");
           myMisc.thumbFileName = photo.getAbsolutePath();
        try {
           FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(photo);
           imageBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 90, out);
            } catch (Exception e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
            }
            is2.close();
            Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(photo);
            photo = null;
            imageBitmap = null;
            imageView.setImageURI(uri);
        }catch(Exception e)
        {
            displayAlert("Can't create file to take picture!","SD Card Error");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Provide the logcat please

Comment: @agamov imageBitmap is null

Comment: damn, i found my error            Bitmap imageBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is2, null, options);
decoding twice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found my error `Bitmap imageBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is2, null, options);` decoding twice

Answer (score 0):

It's probably because of the decodeStream method.

`Bitmap imageBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is2, null, options);`

You parsed null at the when it asks for a Rectangle and when you tried to create a scaled bitmap it was not valid.